# Updating first letter to uppercase using .substr

Tags: javascript, substr, uppercase

im attempting to update the first letter of a string to upper case, **Please note that im only allowed to use .substr and .length to convert it. no regex or anything.**

is this the right method/syntax to do so?

```
e1 = prompt("Please enter your first name", "andrew");

e1.toUpperCase(e1.substr(e1.length - e1.length,0));
```

Comment: You can really use google for this kind of stuff. It's pretty general

Answer (score 0):

Regex everything!

```
e1 = prompt("Please enter your first name", "andrew");
e1.replace(/^\w/, function(t){ return t.toUpperCase() })
```

Comment: Not allowed to use regex, i have to only use substr/ and .length

Part of my class and assignment restriction

Comment: @AndrewBarsoom `e1 = e1.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + e1.substr(1);`